# How can I pipe input to a process?

Tags: php

I am trying to run a program using PHP and keep sending output to it. I've tried using `exec()` but as the documentation page says, it hangs, waiting for the process to return.

Is there something like `exec()` that would allow me to keep sending commands to a CLI application?

Please note that since the application is closed-source, I don't have the option of changing the application to look for a `lock` file or any other thing suggested as answers to similar questions.

Comment: PHP by default does not work asynchronously, and it doesn't have events or callbacks. So I doubt there's an easy way to do it.

Comment: Is there a language better suited to this task, then? What I want to do is like typing `mysql -uroot -proot`, and then sending commands like `use testdb; select * from test;` and so on to the MySQL process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) command. This command runs a process connecting its standard input and output to file descriptors opened as pipes in your program. What you write the 0 descriptor is taken as input on stdin by the process, and what it outputs can be read by your program as of from a file. The example code in the linked php documentation should get you going.

However, if you are trying to communicate with mysql specifically, rather use the built in [mysql functionality of php](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. The `mysql` example was just an example to show what I need; I fortunately was not trying to query the database using this method. :-)